# How does python numpy.where() work?

Tags: python, numpy, magic-methods

I am playing with `numpy` and digging through documentation and I have come across some magic. Namely I am talking about `numpy.where()`:

```
>>> x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
>>> np.where( x > 5 )
(array([2, 2, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]))
```

How do they achieve internally that you are able to pass something like `x > 5` into a method? I guess it has something to do with `__gt__` but I am looking for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> How do they achieve internally that you are able to pass something like x > 5 into a method?

The short answer is that they don't.

Any sort of logical operation on a numpy array returns a boolean array. (i.e. `__gt__`, `__lt__`, etc all return boolean arrays where the given condition is true).

E.g.

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print x > 5
```

yields:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

This is the same reason why something like `if x > 5:` raises a ValueError if `x` is a numpy array.  It's an array of True/False values, not a single value.

Furthermore, numpy arrays can be indexed by boolean arrays. E.g. `x[x>5]` yields `[6 7 8]`, in this case.

Honestly, it's fairly rare that you actually need `numpy.where` but it just returns the indicies where a boolean array is `True`.  Usually you can do what you need with simple boolean indexing.

Comment: Just to point out that `numpy.where` do have 2 'operational modes', first one returns the `indices`, where `condition is True` and if optional parameters `x` and `y` are present (same shape as `condition`, or broadcastable to such shape!), it will return values from `x` when `condition is True` otherwise from `y`. So this makes `where` more versatile and enables it to be used more often. Thanks

Comment: There can also be overhead in some cases using the `__getitem__` syntax of `[]` over either `numpy.where` or `numpy.take`. Since `__getitem__` has to also support slicing, there's some overhead. I've seen noticeable speed differences when working with the Python Pandas data structures and logically indexing very large columns. In those cases, if you don't need slicing, then `take` and `where` are actually better.

Answer (score 25):

**Old Answer**
it is kind of confusing.  It gives you the LOCATIONS (all of them) of where your statment is true.

so:

```
>>> a = np.arange(100)
>>> np.where(a > 30)
(array([31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47,
       48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64,
       65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,
       82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98,
       99]),)
>>> np.where(a == 90)
(array([90]),)

a = a*40
>>> np.where(a > 1000)
(array([26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,
       43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59,
       60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76,
       77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93,
       94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]),)
>>> a[25]
1000
>>> a[26]
1040
```

I use it as an alternative to list.index(), but it has many other uses as well.  I have never used it with 2D arrays.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

**New Answer**
It seems that the person was asking something more fundamental.

The question was how could YOU implement something that allows a function (such as where) to know what was requested.

First note that calling any of the comparison operators do an interesting thing.

```
a > 1000
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True`,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)`
```

This is done by overloading the "__gt__" method.  For instance:

```
>>> class demo(object):
    def __gt__(self, item):
        print item


>>> a = demo()
>>> a > 4
4
```

As you can see, "a > 4" was valid code.

You can get a full list and documentation of all overloaded functions here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Something that is incredible is how simple it is to do this.  ALL operations in python are done in such a way.  Saying a > b is equivalent to a.**gt**(b)!

Comment: This comparison operator overloading doesn't seem to work well with more complex logical expressions though - for example I can't do `np.where(a > 30 and a < 50)` or `np.where(30 < a < 50)` because it ends up trying to evaluate the logical AND of two arrays of booleans, which is pretty meaningless. Is there a way to write such a condition with `np.where`?

Comment: @meowsqueak `np.where((a > 30) & (a < 50))`

Comment: Why is np.where() returning a list in your example?

Answer (score 4):

`np.where` returns a tuple of length equal to the dimension of the numpy ndarray on which it is called (in other words `ndim`) and each item of tuple is a numpy ndarray of indices of all those values in the initial ndarray for which the condition is True. (Please don't confuse dimension with shape)

For example:

```
x=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print(x)
array([[0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8]])
y = np.where(x>4)
print(y)
array([1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64), array([2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

y is a tuple of length 2 because `x.ndim` is 2. The 1st item in tuple contains row numbers of all elements greater than 4 and the 2nd item contains column numbers of all items greater than 4. As you can see, [1,2,2,2] corresponds to row numbers of 5,6,7,8 and [2,0,1,2] corresponds to column numbers of 5,6,7,8
Note that the ndarray is traversed along first dimension(row-wise).

Similarly,

```
x=np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
np.where(x>4)
```

will return a tuple of length 3 because x has 3 dimensions.

But wait, there's more to np.where!

when two additional arguments are added to `np.where`; it will do a replace operation for all those pairwise row-column combinations which are obtained by the above tuple.

```
x=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
y = np.where(x>4, 1, 0)
print(y)
array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a tough time understanding the output, that I received for an input.

```
import numpy as np
pp =  np.array([[True,False,True,True],
               [False,True,False,True]])
np.where(pp)
```

The output was:

```
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 2, 3, 1, 3]))
```

The best way to understand this is to read out the output tuple pair by pair, i.e. `(0,0);(0,2);(0,3);(1,1);(1,3)` and voila, these are the coordinates where the condition was `True`.

So on so forth for higher dimensions.

Comment: THANK YOU. Took me awhile to find this information. Couldn't find it in the documentation of numpy.where.